# How can one resolve duplicate accounts?

Tags: support

if a person asks questions using an unregistered Profile, then creates a registered profile under the same email address, is it possible for the unregistered questions, notifications and reputation to be attached to the registered account? if so how?

Answer (score 4):

Our help center has a page on [merging accounts](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), which to save you the trip says this (it's short):

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please sign into either account, visit the [**contact form**](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.

I suspect the fact you reused your email address might help resolve the confirmation pretty quickly.